# How to control motors from an HTML web page

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am working on a project where the ultimate goal is to control some simple motors through a web page. I created the web page using HTML and now I wonder about the best way to go

I want to send a command to the server after the button is clicked, where a C# script running the motors will pick up the message and then control the motors accordingly. Would the best way to do this be through JSON and/or jQuery?

So far, I have a `.load` function written in jQuery that sends a simple message to the server. Then that function is called upon button press by the HTML document. My main question is, whether this is the best route to go when communicating between HTML, a server, and C#. Thank you.

Comment: I think this would be better suited at webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I dont know if you've thought about it, but dont forget about security. Think about what you need, and them make something *more* secure than that.

Comment: Look into how to write a HTTP server in C#...that would probably make things simpler since you would receive the requests and perform the hardware signals on the same application and language.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother to write a HTTP server in C#. My personal approach will be to use a web server and some classic server side language like PHP or a spring/java endpoint. This will help you a lot with security, flexibility, users management and rights etc. You can then use something to call your C# scripts running the motors from the the server-side scripts. jQuery and json will do just fine in the front-end.

Comment: I will be using an Apache server for this, and it's my first time using one. Would I still need to write a PHP script for the server? Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: You do not relay need PHP. If security is no concern, you could create a simple C# server and you won't be needing Apache too. I was just saying that I think you could manage user sessions, login, logout, json, databases easier with PHP or other server side web oriented scripting.